# How to deserialize XML file which contains list?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to deserialize the xml which contains List of id but it's giving me error "unable to generate temporary class(result=1)", please help me.
Below is my xml file format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<identifiers> 
<Module Name="Doors_Module1" Path="Doors_Module1 ">
    <id value="16"/>
    <id value="15"/>
    <id value="14"/>
    <id value="13"/>
    <id value="12"/>
    <id value="11"/>
    <id value="10"/>
    <id value="9"/>
    <id value="17"/>
    <id value="8"/>
    <id value="7"/>
    <id value="6"/>
    <id value="5"/>
    <id value="4"/>
    <id value="3"/>
    <id value="2"/>
    <id value="1"/>
</Module>
</identifiers>
```

and below is my class for Deserialize that xml:

```
 public class HelperAllIdentifiers
{
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("identifiers")]
    public class identifiers
    {
        public Module Module { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Module")]
    public class Module
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlArrayItem("id", Type = typeof(Attribute))]
        public List<IdValue> FieldList;// { get; set; }
        public Attribute[] ids { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("id")]
    public class IdValue
    {
        [XmlAttribute("value")]// Type=typeof(Attribute))]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the root cause, but your Module class differs from the content of the XML file: There is no property that responds to the attribute "Path".

Comment: Actually I don't need of  attribute "Path" in my result. That's why I am not using that attribute in my class

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleWinForm
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "id")]
    public class Id
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Module")]
    public class Module
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public List<Id> Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "identifiers")]
    public class Identifiers
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Module")]
        public Module Module { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                            <identifiers> 
                            <Module Name=""Doors_Module1"" Path=""Doors_Module1 "">
                                <id value=""16""/>
                                <id value=""15""/>
                                <id value=""14""/>
                                <id value=""13""/>
                                <id value=""12""/>
                                <id value=""11""/>
                                <id value=""10""/>
                                <id value=""9""/>
                                <id value=""17""/>
                                <id value=""8""/>
                                <id value=""7""/>
                                <id value=""6""/>
                                <id value=""5""/>
                                <id value=""4""/>
                                <id value=""3""/>
                                <id value=""2""/>
                                <id value=""1""/>
                            </Module>
                            </identifiers>";

            using (var rdr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var srlzr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Identifiers));
                var result = srlzr.Deserialize(rdr) as Identifiers;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heres is what I do when I have to serialize Xml to a C# class.
http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply prateek, but now i get error : Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <getMetadata xmlns=''> was not expected.